# Table alignment in R Markdown - how to align the TABLE to the left

Tags: r, markdown

I am currently struggeling with table alignment in my R Markdown document. I'd like to align it to the left side - important: not the text, but the table itself!.

This is the current code:

```
\section*{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}

| short | defintion | first usage on page |
|---|---|---|
| etc | et cetera | 1 |
```

In the pdf document the whole table is centered as default and I cannot modify this.

Outcome:

[image]

The goal is to adjust it to the section title. It looks very strange like this.

This is my yaml header right now:

```
---
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 3
    number_section: true
    header-includes:
      - \usepackage{float}
      - \usepackage{placeins}
      - \usepackage[margins=raggedright]{floatrow} #I added this today
    includes:
      before_body: Abstract.tex
fontsize: 11pt
lang: de-DE
geometry: margin=2.5cm
#bibliography: references.bib
link-citations: true
csl: elsevier-harvard.csl
---
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: '2022-05-09'
output: pdf_document
header-includes: 
- \usepackage[margins=raggedright]{floatrow} 
---
\section*{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}

| short | defintion | first usage on page |
|---|---|---|
| etc | et cetera | 1 |
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I don't know why, but it is not working.. I'll add some more info about the yaml header above, maybe there is something which blocks your code to work in my doc